# Gnu screen, using the exec command in .screenrc

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I have added the following lines to my .screenrc

```
bind -c music u exec amixer sset Master,0 5+ >& /dev/null
bind -c music d exec amixer sset Master,0 5- >& /dev/null
bind -c music t exec amixer sset Master,0 toggle >& /dev/null
bind -c music k exec > /home/g/stop.n; pkill mpg123
bind -c music m exec . /home/g/newmusic.sh
bind -c music n exec pkill mpg123
bind -c music s exec . /mnt/1/setnewt.sh 
bindkey "^y" command -c music   # ^y [udt] for volume, [kmns] play/stop music
```

The first three work as expected, but `^yn`, which should kill mpg123, instead kills the app in screen that I happen to be using when I press `^yn`.  How should I be writing it to have the effect I want?